# Make Voronoi Texture follow Curve in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I am trying to create an effect where a object curved object disintegrates by splinters - created by stretched voronoi cells. The issue is I can't figure out how to get the cells to follow the tangent of the curve.

I tried storing the tangent of the curve before converting it to mesh and plugging that into the vector of the voronoi texture like so:

[image]

But this doesn't produce the desired result, which having a number of thin voronoi cells follow the tangent of the curve. You can see how it can work for a single axis in this image:

[image]

Tried variations of align euler to vector and also vector rotating the stretched position vector by a angle controlled by the stored tangent attribute, but alas.

It seems like how this is done in texturing is to use manipulate the UV map. Hoping there is a simpler way.

[image]